# phonegap: ios black space issue on top and bottom?

Tags: android, ios, apache, cordova, phonegap-build

I built my app in ios and android platform using build.phonegap.com

ios was showing black space on top and bottom.

I followed this article http://shout.setfive.com/2014/04/08/phonegap-fixing-black-bars-on-ios7iphone5/

And updated meta tag. Now ios issue is fixed but now android app view is zoomed out.

Can please some guide that how to fix it for both platforms together?

Thanks

Comment: before you add this meta tag does black bar comes in all iOS resolution ?

Comment: `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` is obsolete. I've been trying to get Phonegap of it from their demo. [Viewport target-densitydpi is deprecated #7](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-hello-world/issues/7). However, that is not likely your issue. Recommend [Nitobi forum for Phonegap Build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)

Comment: @Pyro I am not sure I checked in only iPhone 5s

Comment: Don't change the meta tag, the post you link was only right about you were missing a launch image, but you don't have to change the meta tag to fix that problem

Comment: @jcesarmobile, that tag is deprecated and obsolete on some devices. Reported here: [Viewport target-densitydpi is deprecated #7](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-hello-world/issues/7)

Comment: What I meant was, don't change the meta tag to the one on the article he linked, because as you say, it uses deprecated elements and setting the height usually bring problems too